# Add google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine tags

Tags: support, tags

Can someone please add the following tags to Super User:

- [google-cloud-platform](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform)
- [google-compute-engine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine)

I noticed several questions with these tags on Stack Overflow are being closed or put on hold with instructions to take those discussions over to Super User, but those tags don't exist here so it's not possible to tag or follow questions on these topics easily.

Sample questions from Stack Overflow:

- [Google Compute Engine automount disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24388973/3618671): [google-compute-engine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine), [google-cloud](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud)
- [Multiple Static IPs to single GCE VM Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24344637/3618671): [google-compute-engine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine), [ssl](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssl)

Existing questions on Super User that could use [google-compute-engine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine):

- [Login without a password and without authorized_keys](https://superuser.com/q/725577/321938)
- [Where does the httpd.conf reside in GCE Apache?](https://superuser.com/q/743377/321938)

Going a step further, there are additional related tags that it might be worthwhile adding, such as the ones listed on the [[google-cloud-platform]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-cloud-platform/info) tag information page.

Comment: Why?  Question on both are not even on topic at Superuser.  Questions about a google product which only exists in the cloud as a service isn't an appropriate question here at Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound The suggestions to move those questions to SU from SO were made by the admins on the respective questions, not me. Also, there are many tags on SU for various cloud-only services, so there's already precedent.

Comment: Just because there are some tags doesn't mean questions that they would apply to are automatically on topic. Note that people (not admins, just regular users) on Stack Overflow could have not a single clue about what is on topic for us (which, unfortunately, is often the case), and still point people here.

Comment: That being said, if these compute engines work like an Amazon EC2 instance and are basically like an OS you'd also run on your normal PC, I'd say they're fine. Anything that is just about clicking some buttons on a website would be off topic here though.

Comment: @slhck Yes, Google Compute Engine (part of Google Cloud Platform) is a hosted VM environment (IaaS) which works as you describe. Google Cloud Platform also includes AppEngine (PaaS) which is a different programming environment. None of these are point-and-click websites for consumer use; these are systems and tools designed for DevOps use (disclosure: I work on Google Cloud Platform).

Comment: Wouldn't those be better suited for [SF] then? We target home computer users, and Server Fault is more oriented towards large-scale IT and DevOps. I'm not a SF regular though, so I cannot speak for them, unfortunately.

Comment: @slhck Since you mentioned Amazon EC2, please take a look at questions tagged with [`amazon-ec2` on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2), along with questions tagged with amazon-\*, aws-\* and azure-\*. Those are similar in spirit to the questions one might ask in the context of Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me phrase a proper answer. First of all, as I mentioned in a comment, questions about [amazon-ec2](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) seem to be considered on topic here. That would mean the same holds for Google Compute Engine instances.

The Google Cloud Platform as a whole however sounds a bit too enterprise-y to me. We have a few questions about RDS, S3, etc., but those really aren't a lot. I'm guessing people find answers to their AWS questions elsewhere on the Stack Exchange network. Probably [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), [Web Masters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or even Stack Overflow.

I'm not saying that we should ban these outright, but remember that Super User's primary focus is on home computing, not large-scale cloud computing. Running one micro instance on EC2 for your website? Sounds fine. Distributed databases across the globe for your webshop? Meh.

The bottom line is: **We can only add tags to our system if there are questions that are worth applying these tags to.** If you don't have any example questions yet, then there can be no tag.

Comment: I revised the question to add links to existing questions on SU which could use the tag `google-compute-engine`.

Comment: Great, thanks. I added the tag there. What would be great is if you could supply a tag excerpt and a tag wiki similar to what we have for EC2. I guess you'd be in the best position to do that. The tag wiki might link to other relevant tags or documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the [tag wiki](http://superuser.com/tags/google-compute-engine/info) by borrowing liberally from the [SO tag of the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-compute-engine/info).